# Is there a way of actually opening hairpins in LilyPond?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software, lilypond, engraving

I need this for an Ossia staff that only appears for a single bar, like this:

[image: This needs an open hairpin]

The real hairpin starts before that bar (like the 2nd one), but spanning the hairpin where the lower one starts doesn't look accurate, and there's the barline midways.

I know that it can be done with a white box in a markup, but I want to see first if anything like moving the starting points of the hairpin lines can be done, before I try rewriting some things for the Ossia staff.

Also, is there a way to put a text to the side of the Ossia staff that says "Ossia" just like an `instrumentName` but not where the `instrumentName` appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hairpin**

I recommend starting the ossia one measure earlier.

As an example, here is an ossia from Liszt, *Hungarian Rhapsody No. 2* (S.244/2), mm. 378-379 (Peter Raabe *Musikalische Werke* edition). Note that the first ossia measure is identical to the "primary" notation.

[image: Ossia begins with identical measure to accommodate hairpin crescendo starting in that bar]
(IMAGE SOURCE: [IMSLP](https://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/2/26/IMSLP33352-PMLP12453-Liszt_Musikalische_Werke_2_Band_12_118_Ungarische_Rhapsodie_2.pdf))

Alternatively, use "cresc." and a dotted line, if feasible. You can place the ossia "cresc." in parentheses to make clear it's not a new instruction.

**Ossia text**

You can use this code to place the text, adjusting the offsets as needed.

```
    \override InstrumentName.extra-offset = #'(MY-X-OFFSET . MY-Y-OFFSET)
    instrumentName = "Ossia"
```

<sub>Code courtesy of [the accepted answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/98397/70803) to [Lilypond: How to create an ossia Staff above a PianoStaff?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/98339/70803)</sub>